# Mongodb save date with timezone

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, datetime

I want to save date with timezone of singapore. Some of date are coming in singapore timezone and some are not. So i want to change the timezone of all the date (returning from api) to singapore first and then save to database.
Also i want that when i use new Date() (javascript) it automatically give the the date with singapore timezone.
**My questions are:-**
1.How to save all the date in mongo with Asia/Singapore timezone?
2.How to set new Date() timezone to Asia/Singapore ?

Comment: Probably best to do time-conversion within your app, then save accordingly. Seems a bit unusual though, to save to a local time zone vs UTC.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way will be to add (or subtract) the gap between your timezone and the Singapore one, in your application.
Something like
 new Date().AddHours(+- gap);
Which driver are you using?

By the way, why don't you keep another "column" with the timezone id, so you can set the timezone correctly both for your country and for Singapore?

Comment: Why would a column be needed for timezone? If all times are stored in UTC, then translation is easily done in-app with a user-specific setting. Also: Your solution `AddHours()` won't work with timezones not aligning to full hours (e.g. India). That's why Date classes typically have timezone conversion built in.